# I am going to try and post one question a day for one week

Tags: discussion, pledges

This isn't a question, but more so a public commitment to try and up the number of questions that this site has. I commit to do this for one week, starting today, and I will try to keep the quality of questions high.

UPDATE:  I think I posted at least one question a day for the full week. Although, I think the day starts on GMT time or something, so I may have technically missed a day. Either way it was a fun challenge to force myself to think up questions.

Comment: Looking forward to it! We need more questions.

Comment: Agreed, I am planning on the same here.  Nice idea!

Comment: That's a great idea.  I like this pledges tag!

Comment: I hope I'm not discouraging other people from posting questions.

Comment: Have you increased the rate to 1 question every 10 minutes? :V

Comment: Sorry, I'm just trying to run with inspiration as it comes to me.

Comment: I was having a hard time doing this so decided to just start putting in questions I already know the answers too and see how that goes.  Personally I'd like more in-depth questions but most I can come up with I can figure out on my own, not sure about others.

Answer (score 6):

While I appreciate your enthusiasm and I think this is a great idea, I would suggest that you be careful about the types of questions you ask. Any question that starts with "Why" is probably going to end up being closed by a moderator. Questions of this sort are subjective by nature and usually can't be answered with a clear and concise response

Also, I think it would be helpful if you wait at least a day or two to accept someone's answer. Generally, once an answer has been accepted, it discourages others from attempting to answer. On top of that, you don't want to accept the first answer that comes along because someone may end up posting a better response, if you give them enough time to see the question and answer it!

Comment: thanks, good points, and noted

Comment: also, I agree about the "why" questions and have tried to make them as tight as possible

Comment: I have gone through and edited a few of them. Maybe you could look at those and use the as examples for changing some of the others. I'll try to check in again later and help out if I can.

Comment: I'm not sure why type questions are always inappropriate. Sure you can refactor the question, but sometimes implicit in the "why" is the solicitation for factors.

Comment: Also, I normally try to wait, but the BrotherJack answer on the nutrition guidelines was fantastic. But, your concern is 100% correct.

Answer (score 2):

I see you've been keeping to this, as (I think) have some other people. The affects so far on [our statistics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5169/history) have been interesting, I think.

Our Questions-per-day has shot up from around 2.0 to 2.6. Sadly, they feel a "healthy" level is 15, but this is a very good start for such a short period.

However, our answer ratio has dropped to under 2. That's still in the OK range though.

---

EDITS:

One day later, and it's up to 3 questions per day. Wow.

One week +, and it's up over 4. I suspect still climbing. Its not all ihtkwot either. I don't know what's going on, but its cool.

---

For a while we were around 4.5, but it has started to go back down to earth now. 3.0 as I write this. However, our visits per day has continued to increase, which I consider a good sign. Our users stats have gone into the Okay territory as well, and seem to be advancing nicely.

Comment: Questions are good but we need to answer things as well, I have set a goal to try and do one unanswered question a month...since most require a bit of research.

Comment: Agreed.  Over the long term future of the site, having both intriguing questions and high quality answers are going to be key.